# java 8 - how to group by every element from the list

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have 2 lists: 'groups' and 'people'. In the end I want to get a map grouped by every 'group'.
The code below doesn't compile due to last flatMap method, saying that 'Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context'.

```
private static Map<Group, List<Person>> getAllGroupsOfSelectedPeople(List<Person> people) {
       List<Group> groups = getCurrentlyActiveGroups(people);
       return people.stream()
               .filter(p -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(p.getSocials()))
               .filter(p -> p.getGroups().stream().anyMatch(groups::contains))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getGroups().stream().flatMap(List::stream)));
   }
```

Comment: Could you share Group and Person main methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatMap` should be used before the `collect` step, to generate all pairs of `Group` and `Person`. Then you can group these pairs.

```
private static Map<Group, List<Person>> getAllGroupsOfSelectedPeople(List<Person> people) {
       List<Group> groups = getCurrentlyActiveGroups(people);
       return people.stream()
               .filter(p -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(p.getSocials()))
               .filter(p -> p.getGroups().stream().anyMatch(groups::contains))
               .flatMap(p -> p.getGroups()
                              .stream()
                              .map(g -> new SimpleEntry<Group,Person>(g,p)))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                              Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                                 Collectors.toList())));
}
```